# How is it possible to extend GMail?

Tags: gmail

I'd like to write a **gmail extension** that would **add a button on the email page** (or a seclectbox, or anything). For information, the goal is to add a task into my task manager from an email content.

What would be the way of doing it ?
A greasemonkey script is not an option as I would like to do it for Chrome too.

I don't know where to start.

Thanks for any pointers,
Mickael;

Comment: There are plans of integrating greasemonkey and chrome, just google it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the comment stated, Greasemonkey scripts have been integrated into Chrome. An alternative would be to develop an extension (for both FF and Chrome) similar to "Google Redesigned" - one of my favorite FF extensions.